# What do non-experts hope to get out of this site

Tags: discussion

This is the sister question to: [What do experts expect to get out of this SE site?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/62/119) which it was suggested was added.

As we move into public beta we will want to appeal to both experts and non experts.  So it probably would be handy to have a straw poll of why non-experts are coming to an economics stack exchange?  What will keep you contributing?

Again, the category is self defining, you decide if you see yourself as an expert or not.

Answer (score 1):

A place to learn by asking questions I've wondered about, and through seeing other interesting questions I would never have thought of asking. Economics is a field which seems to have a lot of really interesting stuff to say about every day life.